# JSONException trying to get a JSONArray out of the JSON result. No value found for the given array

Tags: android, json

I am using the fatsecret rest API to search for foods in an android foodlogging application. The result I get back is in JSON format.

The result I get back is the following

```
{
  "result": {
    "foods": {
      "food": [
        {
          "food_description": "Per 100g - Calories: 147kcal | Fat: 9.94g | Carbs: 0.77g | Protein: 12.58g",
          "food_id": "3092",
          "food_name": "Egg",
          "food_type": "Generic",
          "food_url": "http://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/generic/egg-whole-raw"
        },
        {
          "food_description": "Per 100g - Calories: 166kcal | Fat: 12.21g | Carbs: 2.20g | Protein: 11.09g",
          "food_id": "33801",
          "food_name": "Scrambled Egg (Whole, Cooked)",
          "food_type": "Generic",
          "food_url": "http://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/usda/scrambled-egg-(whole-cooked)"
        },
        {
          "food_description": "Per 100g - Calories: 201kcal | Fat: 15.31g | Carbs: 0.88g | Protein: 13.63g",
          "food_id": "33797",
          "food_name": "Fried Egg",
          "food_type": "Generic",
          "food_url": "http://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/usda/fried-egg"
        },
        {
          "food_description": "Per 100g - Calories: 155kcal | Fat: 10.61g | Carbs: 1.12g | Protein: 12.58g",
          "food_id": "3094",
          "food_name": "Boiled Egg",
          "food_type": "Generic",
          "food_url": "http://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/generic/egg-whole-boiled"
        },
        {
          "food_description": "Per 100g - Calories: 52kcal | Fat: 0.17g | Carbs: 0.73g | Protein: 10.90g",
          "food_id": "33793",
          "food_name": "Egg White",
          "food_type": "Generic",
          "food_url": "http://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/usda/egg-white"
        }
      ],
      "max_results": "5",
      "page_number": "0",
      "total_results": "832"
    }
  }
}
```

This result is stored inside a JSONObject called food.

Now I am trying to do something like this :

```
JSONArray FOODS_ARRAY = food.getJSONArray("food");
```

But every time I try to do this I get an error called `org.json.JSONException: No value for food.`

Btw I am using org.json.JSONArray.

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong? As far as looking at other posts or JSON documentation idk what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: You need 1st to get "foods" as JSONObject and from that object get "food" as JSONArray...try and post result

Comment: yes. post your full code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try below code :**

```
private void paresResponse(final String response) {

       try{
           final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
           final JSONObject jsonObjectResult = jsonObject.optJSONObject("result");
           final JSONObject jsonObjectFoods = jsonObjectResult.optJSONObject("foods");
           final JSONArray jsonArrayFood = jsonObjectFoods.optJSONArray("food");
           if(jsonArrayFood!=null && jsonArrayFood.length()>0){
               for (int i = 0 ;i < jsonArrayFood.length();i++){
                   final JSONObject jsonObjectFood = jsonArrayFood.optJSONObject(i);
                   if(jsonObjectFood!=null && jsonObjectFood.length()>0){
                       //....other code
                   }
               }
           }
       }catch (JSONException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hey that worked! Thanks a lot. Sorry, I'm still new to JSON.

Comment: Mark this as a correct answer so others getting help with this

Answer (score 0):

Please change food.getJSONArray("food") to foods.getJSONArray("food")

Answer (score 0):

use this code!

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString); //jsonString is the whole response as string
    JSONObject foods = json.getJSONObject("foods");
    JSONArray FOODS_ARRAY = foods.getJSONArray("food");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: For full JSON Response parsing

```
 try{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONObject result = json.getJSONObject("result");
    JSONObject foods = result.getJSONObject("foods");
    JSONArray jsonArray = foods.getJSONArray("food");
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
         JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
         String food_description = object.getString("food_description");
         String food_id = object.getString("food_id");
         //rest of the strings..
        }
    String max_result = foods.getString("max_results");
    String page_number = foods.getString("page_number");
     }
     catch (JSONException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Learn more about JSON parsing from [Here](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/networking/json-parsing-tutorial-android/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Gson` (just add in your dependencies `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'`).

Now you have to create a POJO class. To create the pojo just go [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and for *Source type* option select **JSON** and for *Annotation style* option select **Gson**.

And you `Gson` like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyPojo = gson.fromJson(responseJson, MyPojo.class);
```